# Validating if the check-box is checked

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I am using JQuery for validating if the check-box is checked or not. If Column-A has some value in it, and the check-box should get checked while saving.(I can keep the code in presave function).

Or if i can get an alert when this checkbox is not checked.

```
if($("select[title='Platform']").val()!=null) {
    alert("hi");
    $( '#Feature_x0020_Dependency_6c8e1e07-570a-418a-83c57cee7e963aed_$BooleanField' ).prop( "checked", true );
}
```

It shows syntax error for the ID that I have added for checkbox.

Comment: What all have you written so far?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The reason you get a syntax error is because you need to escape the special character `$`.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
$('#Feature_x0020_Dependency_6c8e1e07-570a-418a-83c57cee7e963aed_$BooleanField').is(":checked")
```

**UPDATE**

Try `$("[id$=_$BooleanField]").is(":checked")` or `$("[id$=_BooleanField]").is(":checked")`

**LEARNING**

Please have a look at following for all jQuery selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

We used id$ selector which means elements ending with id=value.. Following explains:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_end_value.asp

Comment: it shows error 'Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Feature_x0020_Dependency_6c8e1e07-570a-418a-83c5-7cee7e963aed_$BooleanField('

Comment: check the update

Comment: Please add some explanation (or link to reference) about those jQuery selectors, newbie users won't have a clue what is going on.

Comment: @DannyEngelman added. w3schools would do ?

Answer (score 0):

This should as expected:

```
($("#tdLanguage").children().find('input:checkbox').is(':checked'))
```

where #tdLanguage is ID of the field.
For more information, read this article: [Accessing Checkbox in SharePoint using JQuery](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/06/accessing-checkbox-in-sharepoint-using.html)

Answer (score -1):

It works fine with

```
$("[id$=_BooleanField]").is(":checked")
```

thanks